# How to set timezone in Laravel 5.8 for West Virginia

Tags: php, laravel-5, timezone

How to set properly timezone in Laravel Web Application for West Virginia.

Unable to find out Virginia in the list https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php :(

Currently, I have entered in .env file `APP_TIMEZONE=America/Tortola` but the problem is how to config daylight saving, and what is appropriate timezone for West Virginia?

Comment: Why would you pick Tortola? That's in the Virgin Islands, in the Atlantic timezone. West Virginia is in Eastern Time. Just use `America/New_York`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every city/state is listed as a Timezone identifier. For example, my city isn't, but `America/Toronto` is "close-enough" (same Timezone, EST), so I use that. A quick Google search says that Virginia is EST, so that (or any other `America/{City}` combination that uses `EST`) should work for you.

Edit: As stated below in a couple comments, `America/New_York` is more acceptable for a city based in the United States.

As for how to set the `.env` value `APP_TIMEZONE`, you need to use the `.env` helper:

`.env`:

```
APP_TIMEZONE=America/New_York
```

`config/app.php`:

```php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'),
```

The `env()` helper checks for a value from `.env`, and uses that if available, or uses the 2nd param as a default (`'UTC'` in this case)

Edit: DST (Daylight Savings Time) should be automatic. Using the above shows the correct time with DST included:

> date: 2019-12-05 10:32:06.624748 America/New_York (-05:00)

Comment: For a US-based city, `America/New_York` will work as well.

Comment: It's more than that, `America/New_York` and `America/Toronto` have not always been the same.  They last differed (in terms of DST dates) in 1975.  `America/New_York` is correct for West Virginia.  (The rest of the answer is good.)

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Thanks for that info, as if dates needed to be more complicated eh? Answer has been updated to use `America/New_York` in examples. Cheers!